# How can I create a customise ubuntu to open browser when booted and restrict access to other application

Tags: bootloader, customization, restricted

I am trying to create a custom OS for examination purposes and I want to customize ubuntu iso so that it when booted it has only access to a browser and no other application

Comment: are you mean shrink ubuntu on internet explorer

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for what's called a kiosk. See docs on Ubuntu kiosk mode: https://mir-server.io/docs/make-a-secure-ubuntu-web-kiosk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to launch google-chrome/chromium application shortcut in fullscreen/kiosk mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358898/how-to-launch-google-chrome-chromium-application-shortcut-in-fullscreen-kiosk-mo)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customize Ubuntu for a library Internet kiosk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124759/customize-ubuntu-for-a-library-internet-kiosk)

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you all details to complete your task, but I have a distribution which at boot start a browser which connects itself to a specific URL that to a specific IP address.

Essentially you need the following steps:

### Script to start the browser (in kiosk mode)

You have to create the bash script `start-browser.sh` and save in in the folder `Save it in the home folder` /home/username`. I suppose you are using Firefox as browser, so the content of the script at least the followed command:

```
/usr/bin/firefox --kiosk <URL> &
```

In the previous script is present only a command where:

- you have to set the `<URL>`
- Firefox is started with the option `--kiosk` but this option can be removed if it isn't necessary; this option restricts the access to the other applications present in the distribution

Remember to set executable the script by:

```
sudo chmod +x /home/username/start-browser.sh
```

### Start the script by Autostart

To start the script at boot I suggest you to add the script to the `Autostart` of the Desktop Manager by the menu `Preferences`. In this moment I don't have a Ubuntu distribution installed but only a lubuntu distribution. In lubuntu 22.04 to add `start-browser.sh` to the `Autostart` you have to select, by the Start button the menu:

```
Preference->LXQT Settings->Session Settings->Autostart
```

In this moment is not easy for me add useful screenshot to reach this menu and show how to add the script for Autostart.

---

I think with the previous two steps at boot, the Ubuntu distribution start Firefox at full screen and in kiosk mode.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest install ubuntu and customize it (add/remove apps,packages,commands) after then you can [make `filesystem.squashfs` from ubuntu partition](https://askubuntu.com/a/1474413/1698042) that can be used to [make live usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474717/create-usb-drive-contains-multi-ubuntu-versions-hbcd-pe-64-and-multi-windows-in).

### add app to autostart:

1. get `yourapp.desktop` for this app.
2. copy this yourapp.desktop to `/etc/xdg/autostart`.
3. reboot, when login to ubuntu the app will start automaticly after short time.

   you can remove or add any `.desktop` to `/etc/xdg/autostart` to take control on your ubuntu start apps.

    **related:**
   [how-to-limit-user-access-to-selected-applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350297/how-to-limit-user-access-to-selected-applications)

### related customization tools and ways:

1. https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic
2. https://github.com/mvallim/live-custom-ubuntu-from-scratch
3. https://www.debuntu.org/how-to-customize-your-ubuntu-live-cd/index.html
4. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization
5. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch